# Как сделать границы карты?

Tags: unity3d

Всем доброго. Понимаю что вопрос банален для многих, но мне не ясно как это сделать.
У меня есть карта ресурсов (gameObject - Map), ширина и высота которой определяеться в коде.

```
// Определяем ширину и высоту Map
        gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal,
            MapGeneration.Instanse.Width * 0.48f);
        gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Vertical,
            MapGeneration.Instanse.Height * 0.48f);
```

Width и Height - это количество ресурсов которое будет определять эти же параметры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашёл код который ограничивает движение камеры

```
// borders
[SerializeField] private float left;
[SerializeField] private float right;
[SerializeField] private float bottom;
[SerializeField] private float top;

private void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(
        Mathf.Clamp(Player.Instanse.transform.position.x, left, right),
        Mathf.Clamp(Player.Instanse.transform.position.y, bottom, top),
        transform.position.z);
}
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.magenta;
    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(left, top), new Vector2(right, top));
    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(left, bottom), new Vector2(right, bottom));
    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(left, top), new Vector2(left, bottom));
    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(right, top), new Vector2(right, bottom));
}
```

И он хорошо работает, не выпускает камеру за нарисование границы(квадрат)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я не знаю как подстроить это ограничение. Для меня не понятно как изъять от Map крайние точки и
использовать их в границах карты.
Как мне правильно реализовать границы(2-ой слайд) чтобы игрок и камера не выходили за них?

Comment: игрок похож на саженец березы из minecraft-а :D

Comment: @Alex alexeev, да, но это чисто для примера. визуал будет другой)

Comment: сорри я на юнити не прогаю подожди немного тебе обязательно помогут

Comment: У Tilemap есть свойства size.x/size.y, которые определяют количество "ячеек" по горизонтали и вертикали. В дополнение к этому есть cellsize, которое определяет размер каждой ячейки. По факту Вы можете получить размеры вашей карты и найти координаты её углов, дальше, я думаю, Вы справитесь.

Answer (score 0):

```
// bounds
private float left, right, bottom, top;
private void Start()
{
    left = MapGeneration.Instanse.Width * -0.24f;
    right = MapGeneration.Instanse.Width * 0.24f;
    bottom = MapGeneration.Instanse.Height * -0.48f;
    top = 5;
}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(
        Mathf.Clamp(Player.Instanse.transform.position.x, left + 0.24f, right - 0.24f),
        Mathf.Clamp(Player.Instanse.transform.position.y, bottom, top),
        transform.position.z);
}
```

В общем так я решил границы карты а с камерой ещё не получилось. Чёт там сложно из-за перевода с розришения екрана в unit-pixels + там дальность самой камеры идёт в счёт. Я так и не понял.